# Do kernel NFS module have concurrent limit?

Tags: concurrency, io, linux-kernel, nfs

Background: I was testing a nfs-server with `fio`. And I find that no matter how much "iodepth" is set to `fio`. The nfs-server can only have "64 Inflight". So I just suspect that somewhere around "nfs protocol" limits the max concurrent(max io in flight).

`fio` command is

```
fio -numjobs=1 -iodepth=128 -direct=1 -ioengine=libaio -sync=1 -rw=write -bs=4k -size=500M -time_based -runtime=90 -name=Fiow -directory=/75
```

My nfs-server is based on ganesha, and got conclusion "64 Inflight" by using `ganesha_stats.py`.

So I have two options for now:

1. Study the calling-graph and read code to find the problem

   1. I download linux kernel code, but struggle to . Which function/source file should I begin , maybe vfs.c:nfsd_write?
   2. Tried to use 'perf' to trace calling-graph to speed up my code reading tour for linux kernel, but failed. Because 'perf report' shows shared library symbol without function name.
2. Learn the nfs protocol/mount cmd to seek the limit.

Can somebody can help me with this? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using NFSv4.1 ([RFC 5661](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5661#section-2.10.6.1)):

> In NFSv4.1, the number of outstanding requests is bounded by the size of the slot table [...].

And in [Linux](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.10/source/fs/nfs/nfs4session.h#L12):

```
#define NFS4_DEF_SLOT_TABLE_SIZE (64U)
```

It is the default for [this module param](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.10/source/fs/nfs/super.c#L2995):

```
module_param(max_session_slots, ushort, 0644);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(max_session_slots, "Maximum number of outstanding NFSv4.1 "
        "requests the client will negotiate");
```

IIUC the [total maximum](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.10/source/fs/nfs/nfs4session.h#L14) for this is:

```
#define NFS4_MAX_SLOT_TABLE (1024U)
```